# Ext.Net:Radiogroup,make it selected from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ext.net

I have radiogruop control like this;

```
<ext:RadioGroup ID="rdyAktifmi" runat="server" FieldLabel="Aktifmi" Width="150"
    Flex="1">
  <Items>
   <ext:Radio ID="Radio4" runat="server" BoxLabel="pasif" InputValue="0" />
   <ext:Radio ID="Radio5" runat="server" BoxLabel="aktif" InputValue="1" />

  </Items>
  </ext:RadioGroup>
```

how I can set  the RadioGroup  value codebehind.I have 2 values come from database 1 and 0.
depensd on this values ,i wanna make selected Radio4 or Radio5.(it will be only one selected radiobox)

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259637/ext-net-radiogruop-make-selected-radiobutton-depend-on-its-inputvalue/17312517#17312517

Answer (score 1):

```
        int radioActivateIndex = 0;
        //set radioActivateIndex to wich one you want to activate here

        if (radioActivateIndex==0)
        {
            Radio4.SetValue(true);
            Radio5.SetValue(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Radio4.SetValue(false);
            Radio5.SetValue(true);
        }
```

If more than 2 radios use switch-case of course.